# How to control dimension broadcast in tensorflow?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, tensorflow

I would like to center my set of rows with several means and get several sets of centered rows.

My data has shape of `(4, 3)` i.e. four 3D vectors:

```
data = tf.get_variable("myvar1", shape=[4, 3], dtype=tf.float64)
```

I have two centers (two 3D vectors):

```
mu = tf.get_variable("mu", initializer=tf.constant(np.arange(2*3).reshape(2, 3), dtype=tf.float64))
```

I would like to center data once per each mu. In numpy I would write loop:

```
data = np.arange(4 * 3).reshape(4, 3)
mu = np.arange(2*3).reshape(2, 3)

centered_data = np.empty((2, 4, 3))
for i_data in range(len(data)):
    for i_mu in range(len(mu)):
        centered = data[i_data] - mu[i_mu]
        centered_data[i_mu, i_data, :] = centered
```

How to do the same in tensorflow?

Bulk method for numpy would also be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I can insert singular dimension to provoke broadcasting:

```
data = tf.get_variable("myvar1", shape=[4, 3], dtype=tf.float64)
mu = tf.get_variable("mu", initializer=tf.constant(np.arange(2*3).reshape(2, 3), dtype=tf.float64))

centered_data = data - tf.expand_dims(mu, axis=1)

with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    ans_value, centered_data_value, mu_value = sess.run([centered_data, data, mu], {data: np.arange(4 * 3).reshape(4, 3)})

    print("centered_data_value: ", centered_data_value)
    print("mu: ", mu_value)
    print("ans: ", ans_value)
```

The same is in numpy:

```
mu = np.reshape(mu, (2, 1, 3))
centered_data = data - mu
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use `-` or `tf.substract` it will do element wise operation then:

```
centered_data = tf.substract(data, mu)
```

Comment: You are subtracting one mean vector from dataset, this is just normal broadcast, while I want to subtract several